# echo the any particular client to particular project

Tags: php, mysql

I have created a simple Business Management setup for office work. First I fetch all information from database. All is going well except the quantity input.

i creat  a simple client-Payment System in php. in this first Add any client it's doing simple and all client show at a simple page when click a client name then this page go on the project page when add new project name then all project are show on this page. I want the perticualr client name to pericular project show

```
<?php session_start(); include("sidebar.php"); include "config.php"; $sel="select * from new_project"; $rs=mysql_query($sel); ?> 
<div class="h_right">
   <h1> <a href="new_project.php?id=<?php echo $rec['id'] ?>">+ADD New Project</a> </h1>
</div>
<div class="h_left">
   <table border="2px" cellpadding="10px">
      <tr>
         <td>Id</td>
         <td>Project Name</td>
      </tr>
      <?php while($rec=mysql_fetch_assoc($rs)) { ?> 
      <tr>
         <td><?php echo $rec['id'] ?></td>
         <td><a href="projectdetail.php?><?php echo $rec['project_name'] ?></a></td>
         <?php } ?> 
   </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a foreach loop:

```
<?php session_start(); include("sidebar.php"); include "config.php"; $sel="select * from new_project"; $rs=mysql_query($sel); ?> 
    <div class="h_right">
       <h1> <a href="new_project.php">+ADD New Project</a> </h1>
    </div>
    <div class="h_left">
       <table border="2px" cellpadding="10px">
          <tr>
             <td>Id</td>
             <td>Project Name</td>
          </tr>
          <?php foreach($rec=mysql_fetch_assoc($rs) as $project) { ?> 
          <tr>
             <td><?php echo $rec['id'] ?></td>
             <td><a href="projectdetail.php?id=<?php echo $project['id'] ?>"><?php echo $project['project_name'] ?></a></td>
             <?php } ?> 
       </table>
    </div>
```

new_project.php doesn't need a project id

projectdetail.php will display project based on the project id passed

Comment: this error show

Warning: Illegal string offset 'project_name' in D:\xampp\htdocs\project\clientdetail.php on line 19
8